# Can a character or monster move a grappled enemy to another space in its reach without dragging them?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, combat, grapple, forced-movement

The rules on "[Grappling](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#Grappling)", specifically the "Moving a Grappled Target" section of the PHB (page 195) reads:

> When you move, you can drag or carry the grappled creature with you, but your speed is halved, unless the creature is two or more sizes smaller than you

I wondered if monsters like the death kiss (VGM page 124), that can grapple creatures within a large reach (in this case, 15 feet) can move a grappled creature from a space in its reach to another space in its reach, without dragging it. Is this possible?

Comment: Is this question any different than [this question from earlier today](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/154096/how-much-can-a-grappler-with-reach-move-a-grappled-creature-inside-its-reach)? They seem like the same thing to me, but I can't currently nominate either to be closed as a duplicate because neither have an upvoted answer.

Comment: I agree, and tried to nominate this question as soon as I realized. I'm not sure what the protocol here is.

Comment: I've closed this question as a duplicate of the other one now.